# Any PHP Design Patterns to Handle Command Line Arguments?

Tags: php, arrays, class, design-patterns, factory-pattern

So I am writing a class that needs to accept arguments, some arguments are mandatory, others are optional.

For example: php test.php -a app1 -u username -p password --l --dump-data

The last two with double dashes are optional.

The -a arguments chooses an app, there are several apps such as app2, app3, app4 which are all classes that are in same directory. --l does a list mode which parses the data and its one function that will do that, --dump-data will be a dump of database data. List mode is the prettier version of --dump-data. So basically each argument is a function that shows data in a certain format.

I am using a Factory pattern to let the test.php main class choose which app to use. Not all the complete code but it should give you a good idea.

```
Class Test {
    public static function factory($app, $username, $password, $mode) {
        switch ($app) {
        case 'app1':
            $obj = new app1();
            $obj->login($username, $password, $mode);
            break;
        case 'test':
            $obj = new app2();
            $obj->login($username, $password, $mode);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Could not find that app '" . $app . "'", 1000);
    }
    return $obj;
    }

}

// Code to handle arguments
$longopts  = array(
    "l",    
    "dump-data"
);
$options = getopt("a:u:p:", $longopts);

$mode = array();
foreach($options as $key => $value) {
    if($value == '') {
        $mode[] = $key;
    }
}

$test = Test::factory($options['a'], $options['u'], $options['p'],  $mode);
```

As you see i am passing $mode which contains an array of all the long opts. It will be something like this if i include --l and --dump-data

```
Array
(
[0] => l
[1] => dump-data
)
```

So the trick here is that if i pass $mode to $obj->login($username, $password, $mode);
I will be then having to handle the logic on the app, means each app will have to have identical if statements. For example inside an app class:

```
if($mode[1] == 'dump-data') {
    print_r($data) // print non formatted data dump from database
} else {
    $this->listmode($data); // send dump data to list function so it can print it pretty.
}
```

So trying to find a way that I don't have to repeat this code on every single app class. Also don't want to repeat code on the switch statements which was my first thought, call a function if an argument is present or not. Any ideas or thoughts are welcome. thx

Answer (score 0):

Have each app extend a base abstract app class, then put the common code in the abstract. The `$mode` parameter probably doesn't belong as an argument on the `login()` class, it seems to have nothing to do with that specifically. I'd move it to the constructor.

```
abstract class AbstractApp
{

    protected $mode = null;

    public function __construct($mode)
    {
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    // put your login method here if it's the same for every app
    public function login($user, $pass)
    {
    }

    public function process($data)
    {
        if ($this->mode) === 'dump-data') {
            print_r($data);
        } else {
            $this->listmode($data);
        }
    }

}

class App1 extends AbstractApp
{
    // put your listmode method here if it's custom to this app
    public function listmode($data)
    {
    }
}
```

You also don't have to add a case statement for each app, you can just use the app name itself. Just make sure the app name matches the class name that defines it. For example:

```
class Test
{
    public static function factory($app, $user, $pass, $mode)
    {

        // I'd recommend putting the app classes in their own namespace
        // so that you can easily whitelist them just by their existence.
        $class = '\\MyProject\\App\\' . $app;
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new Exception('No such app.');
        }

        $obj = new $class($mode);
        $obj->login($user, $pass);
        return $obj;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is something to try, i thought about an interface but need to have some code inside the class. Abstract class might be perfect, all apps have listmode, dump-data functions so i just need to call them. I do extend a Curlcall class with App1 already. I want to keep it separate from the Abstract class. But we can't extend two classes... I could extend Curlcall class in the Abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

A significant number of well known tools are using the [Symfony/Console](https://github.com/symfony/console) component to handle command line parsing and output. The Composer tool is one such example.

It doesn't even have to be used as part of a Symfony application either - the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/usage.html) shows how it can be used on it's own for one or more commands as you like.

```
<?php

# example code snippets taken from https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html
# defining arguments in a command
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        // ...
        ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Who do you want to greet?')
        ->addArgument('last_name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Your last name?')
    ;
}

# Using arguments
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $text = 'Hi '.$input->getArgument('name');

    $lastName = $input->getArgument('last_name');
    if ($lastName) {
        $text .= ' '.$lastName;
    }

    $output->writeln($text.'!');
}
```

Comment: The arguments are easy to handle its handling them and having a design pattern of some sort to isolate them and don't repeat code. Check response by Alex Howansky.